# How to call circleCI environment variable in an Angular 2+ project?

Tags: angular, cypress, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I have an angular project that has an api-keys.ts file that looks like this:

```
export var masterFirebaseConfig = {apiKey: $fireBaseApiKey, authDomain: 'dataJitsu.firebaseapp.com',databaseURL: 'https://datajitsu.firebaseio.com',storageBucket: '',messagingSenderId: '495992924984'};
```

I *think* the `$fireBaseApiKey` is stored as an environment variable in my project on circleCI, as you can see in the picture here:

[image]

However, I still get the following error when I run my configuration on circleCI:

> ERROR in src/app/api-keys.ts(1,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name
>   '$fireBaseApiKey'. src/app/app.module.ts(75,11): error TS2304: Cannot
>   find name 'apiKey'.

(The error in app.module.ts comes directly from the error in api-keys.ts)

I tried to figure out whether the problem was on the circleCI side or with how I was plugging it into Angular, so I tried to `echo` out the environmental variable in my configuration file:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.0.1
steps:
  - run:
      name: Setup Environment Variables
      command: |
        echo '$fireBaseApiKey'
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/install:
          build: 'npm run build'
          context: fireBaseApiKey
      - cypress/run:
          requires:
            - cypress/install
          start: 'npm start'
          context: fireBaseApiKey
```

I ssh'ed into the session after it errored out, and I couldn't see any indication 
that my echo command was even acknowledged.

I am hopeful that help on the `echo` front or on the Angular front will be productive to address the question/problem.

Furthermore, I am using cypress for integration testing and thus am using Cypress's orb for setting up and running the tests. I wasn't sure how to/whether environment variables to infiltrate orb jobs, so I also added the variable to a context for the project (with both the context and the key of the lone key-value pair having the same name):

[image]

Update: here is the output from the circleCI log file:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [
>   '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ] 2 info
>   using npm@6.4.1 3 info using node@v10.13.0 4 verbose run-script [
>   'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ] 5 info lifecycle
>   data-jitsu@0.0.0~prebuild: data-jitsu@0.0.0 6 info lifecycle
>   data-jitsu@0.0.0~build: data-jitsu@0.0.0 7 verbose lifecycle
>   data-jitsu@0.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true 8 verbose
>   lifecycle data-jitsu@0.0.0~build: PATH:
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/root/project/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>   9 verbose lifecycle data-jitsu@0.0.0~build: CWD: /root/project 10
>   silly lifecycle data-jitsu@0.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'ng build' ] 11
>   silly lifecycle data-jitsu@0.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal:
>   null 12 info lifecycle data-jitsu@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build
>   script 13 verbose stack Error: data-jitsu@0.0.0 build: `ng build` 13
>   verbose stack Exit status 1 13 verbose stack     at
>   EventEmitter.
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
>   13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13) 13
>   verbose stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
>   13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) 13
>   verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16) 13
>   verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:251:5) 14 verbose pkgid data-jitsu@0.0.0 15
>   verbose cwd /root/project 16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-141-generic 17
>   verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
>   18 verbose node v10.13.0 19 verbose npm  v6.4.1 20 error code
>   ELIFECYCLE 21 error errno 1 22 error data-jitsu@0.0.0 build: `ng
>   build` 22 error Exit status 1 23 error Failed at the data-jitsu@0.0.0
>   build script. 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There
>   is likely additional logging output above. 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out, although probably in a hacky way. I just used `sed` to substitute my environment variable into my api-keys.ts file.

So, here's the new config.yml script (note the extensive changes, including `wait-on: 'http-get://localhost:4200'` (note the http-get there instead of http!).

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.5.1
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/project
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.6.1-browsers
    environment:
      circleCiApiKey: fireBaseApiKey
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Show current branch
          command: |
            echo ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
            ls -larth
            echo $fireBaseApiKey
            cat src/app/api-keys.ts
            sed -i "s/circleCiApiKey/$fireBaseApiKey/g" src/app/api-keys.ts
            cat src/app/api-keys.ts
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{checksum "package.json"}}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Install local dependencies
          command: |
            npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dependencies-{{checksum "package.json"}}
          paths:
            - node_modules
      - run:
          name: Building
          command: npm run build
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dist-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_BRANCH}}-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1}}
          paths:
            - dist
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build:
    jobs:
      - build
      - cypress/install:
          requires:
            - build
          build: 'npm run build'
      - cypress/run:
          requires:
            - cypress/install
            - build
          start: 'npm start'
          store_artifacts: true
          wait-on: 'http-get://localhost:4200'
```

The substitution occurs on the `sed -i "s/circleCiApiKey/$fireBaseApiKey/g" src/app/api-keys.ts` line.

The api-keys.ts file, in turn contains:

```
export var masterFirebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "circleCiApiKey",
    authDomain: "dataJitsu.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://datajitsu.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "495992924984"
  };

export var masterStripeConfig = {
  publicApiTestKey: "xxxxx",
  secretApiTestKey: "xxxxx",
  publicApiKey: "",
  secretApiKey: ""
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `echo $fireBaseApiKey` (without quotes)?

To troubleshoot CircleCI, it's useful to launch an image locally.

Example: the command below will launch a local ubuntu instance with an environment variable `fireBaseApiKey` set to `asdf-asdf-asdf`. Your local files will be mounted in `/usr/src/app`.

```
docker run -it -e fireBaseApiKey=asdf-asdf-asdf -v $PWD:/usr/src/app ubuntu bash
```

To check your environment variable, try:

```
echo $fireBaseApiKey
```

`cd /usr/src/app` and run your build script, step by step. I find it useful to troubleshoot builds failing for unknown reasons.

Comment: Thanks, @Andre Castoldi! I can see my environment variable in the local ubuntu instance per your instructions above, but I still can't see it in my log files on circleCI when I remove the single quotes. I'll be sure to add what I see in my circleCI logfile above.

Comment: Also, the local ubuntu instance looks like it doesn't have npm installed, etc., which all seem to be taken care of with the cypress orb in my config. file. I see theoretically how using a local ubuntu instance would be helpful for troubleshooting, but I'm afraid I'm not equipped to figure out how to run orbs locally.

Comment: In any case, I think what is really needed is an example of how someone else runs cypress on their angular project while keeping API keys private by using environment variables. I can't seem to find a good example of that (in particular, what the config scrip would look like).