# CircleCI error your tests likely make requests to this 'baseUrl' and these tests will fail if you don't boot your server

Tags: angular, circleci, cypress, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am running an Angular 2+ app with integration testing using Cypress.io and CI using circleCI.

I riffed off of a tutorial provided [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/our-journey-for-using-circleci-2-0-to-build-and-deploy-an-angular-app-to-aws-s3-8e7ea3f51503) for setting up an Angular project with circleCI, but needed to add the cypress orbs as well to run Cypress. So I ended up with the following config.yml script:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.0.1
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/project
    docker:
      - image: angular/ngcontainer
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Show current branch
          command: |
            echo ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
            echo $fireBaseApiKey
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{checksum "package.json"}}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Install local dependencies
          command: |
            npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dependencies-{{checksum "package.json"}}
          paths:
            - node_modules
      - run:
          name: Building
          command: npm run build
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dist-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_BRANCH}}-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1}}
          paths:
            - dist
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build:
    jobs:
      - build
      - cypress/install:
          requires:
            - build
          build: 'npm run build'
          context: fireBaseApiKey
      - cypress/run:
          requires:
            - cypress/install
            - build
          start: 'npm start'
          context: fireBaseApiKey
```

When circleCI kicks off, the first two jobs of the workflow are successful (build and cypress/install), but cypress/run produces the following error:

> Cypress could not verify that the server set as your 'baseUrl' is
>   running:
>
> > http://localhost:4200
>
> Your tests likely make requests to this 'baseUrl' and these tests will
>   fail if you don't boot your server.
>
> Please start this server and then run Cypress again.

I'm guessing that I did not boot the server with the `npm run build` command.

I tried adding:

```
- run:
          name: start ng server
          command: ng serve
```

in the "build" job, but then the error was:

> /bin/bash: ng: command not found

I tried to find a docker container on dockerhub that would execute ng commands and "angular/ngcontainer" seemed like a good candidate because using circleci/node:6.10-browsers as my docker image per the tutorial link also didn't recognize ng commands.

I guess I'm mostly just way out of my depth here and haven't been able to find an example of an Angular project that uses Cypress and runs CI on circleCI. Having such an example would probably go a long way in helping things make sense. Until then, does anyone have any recommendations for how I might execute a command like `ng serve` and do you suppose that would solve my server not booting error?

Update 3 Feb., 2019 19:34:

I added `wait-on` after looking into [the cypress orb usage](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/cypress-io/cypress#usage-start-server) a little more per advice advice from a friend on the internet. Thus, my updated `-cypress/run` command reads:

```
...
- cypress/run:
          requires:
            - cypress/install
            - build
          start: 'npm start'
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:4200'
          context: fireBaseApiKey
```

This seems to wait for an 'http://localhost:4200' that never happens.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? im having the same issue but on my Jenkins pipeline

Comment: Not yet. Working with one of the cypress devs on Twitter. Will likely be posting an issue on github about it this weekend.

Comment: Ok cool, could you please tag me whereisjefe and I can help provide some additional debug info

Comment: @Atticus29 Could you link the issue here so others stumbling on this issue can follow along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were actually a few issues here:

1. It seems I needed to use http-get instead of http. So: `wait-on: 'http-get://localhost:4200'`
2. I was still having some issues with my environment variables, which were asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263826/how-to-call-circleci-environment-variable-in-an-angular-2-project).

So, the final config file ended up looking like:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.5.1
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/project
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.6.1-browsers
    environment:
      circleCiApiKey: fireBaseApiKey
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Show current branch
          command: |
            echo ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
            ls -larth
            echo $fireBaseApiKey
            cat src/app/api-keys.ts
            sed -i "s/circleCiApiKey/$fireBaseApiKey/g" src/app/api-keys.ts
            cat src/app/api-keys.ts
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{checksum "package.json"}}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Install local dependencies
          command: |
            npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dependencies-{{checksum "package.json"}}
          paths:
            - node_modules
      - run:
          name: Building
          command: npm run build
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dist-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_BRANCH}}-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1}}
          paths:
            - dist
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build:
    jobs:
      - build
      - cypress/install:
          requires:
            - build
          build: 'npm run build'
      - cypress/run:
          requires:
            - cypress/install
            - build
          start: 'npm start'
          store_artifacts: true
          wait-on: 'http-get://localhost:4200'
```

With the api-key.ts file referenced in the `sed` statement looking like:

```
export var masterFirebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "circleCiApiKey",
    authDomain: "dataJitsu.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://datajitsu.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "495992924984"
  };

export var masterStripeConfig = {
  publicApiTestKey: "pk_test_NKyjLSwnMosdX0mIgQaRRHbS",
  secretApiTestKey: "sk_test_6YWZDNhzfMq3UWZwdvcaOwSa",
  publicApiKey: "",
  secretApiKey: ""
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think i can help with the `ng command not found` problem.

You need to install the angular cli in your dev dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Then after `npm install` runs in your script `ng` will exist so you can add your `ng serve` step to start your server.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s already in my package.json, but really good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think this will apply to you, this question did popup for me when I was googling my issue. So in case another person has similar issue, here is how I got it working.

To get some NPM packages to work in our environment, I needed to use our corporate proxy and set it via `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables in my Jenkins Pipeline. After a bit of debugging, noticed that cypress was trying to do something with the proxy. Once I set `NO_PROXY = localhost` cypress connected, success!